# php can't move file from tmp

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm stuck with a simple php code, which must move a uploaded file from tmp to a desired location. Please find my code below. I'm not sure where i'm going wrong.
Any help is appreciated.

php code:

```
<?php
define("UPLOAD_DIR", "/srv/www/wordpress/mywebpage/uploads/");
   $scr = $_FILES["jb_cv"]["tmp_name"];
   $desttmp = $_FILES["jb_cv"]["name"];
     $dest =  UPLOAD_DIR .$desttmp;

      echo " source file : ";
      echo $scr."\t";
    echo " destination file : ";
    echo $dest;

   $success = move_uploaded_file($scr,$dest);   

    if (!$success) {
        echo "<p>Unable to save file.</p>";             
        exit;
    } 
?>
```

HTML code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Form</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Enter your name</h1>

    <form method="post" action="move.php" id="contactform" name="contactform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <label> Upload your CV</label> <input name="jb_cv" type="file" />                        
                                    <input  type="submit" value="SUBMIT" />


    </form>

    </body>
    </html
```

Comment: Please check folder permission

Comment: Did you check permissions for file creation in UPLOAD_DIR?

Comment: Is `WARNING` issued by PHP? http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

Comment: no.. no warning was issued

Comment: Thanks it was the folder permissions. Aft all this time i can't believe i didn't check this.